# Latest version is not available on Marketplace (available: M91; latest: M94)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-dl-platform

I keep getting error messages when trying to deploy either PyTorch or base Intel MKL frameworks related to the Debian image being deprecated.  It looks like that the latest release of this deployment is M94, however, the version available on the Marketplace is M91. Appreciate your help!

Comment: what "marketplace"?

Comment: Tge one on Google Cloud Platform -- is there another way to deploy this image?

Comment: not a programming issue. try https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ or contact whoever deals with those packages on those marketplaces -- please review: [ask], [help/on-topic]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ah i had forgotten to tag my question appropriately, which i now fixed. thanks for your input anyways!